# Neo4j java multiple session

Tags: java, session, neo4j, drivers

How can i create multiple session for neo4j in java using this driver org.neo4j.driver.v1?

I'm able to create a single session with this instruction:

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost", +

AuthTokens.basic(neo4j, password), Config.build()
            .withEncryptionLevel( Config.EncryptionLevel.REQUIRED )
            .withTrustStrategy( Config.TrustStrategy.trustOnFirstUse( new File( "/path/to/neo4j_known_hosts" ) ) )
            .toConfig() );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code sample, you're not creating a `Session`, only a `Driver`.

The `Session` is created by calling [`driver.session()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/1.1/org/neo4j/driver/v1/Driver.html#session--). If you want multiple sessions, you just call the method multiple times on the same `Driver` instance, e.g. if you're querying Neo4j while handling concurrent HTTP requests in your web application.